# Can I save on compute (and money) by lowering snowflake timestamp precision?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have snowflake tables. I don't care too much about sub-second precision. I see that the default precision of snowflake timestamps is 9 digits past the decimal. (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime#timestamp)

I want to know if i specify '0', will i save on compute time? Or does snowflake store and operate on this data the same way, so i won't save anything?